# Combine multiple sed commands into one

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file `example.txt`, I want to delete and replace fields in it.

The following commands are good, but in a very messy way, unfortunately I'm a rookie to `sed` command.

The commands I used:

`sed 's/\-I\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.//\n/g' example.txt > example.txt1`

`sed 's/\-I/\n/g' example.txt1 > example.txt2`

`sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' > example.txt2 example.txt3`

`sed 's/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.//g' > example.txt3 example.txt`

and then I'm deleting all the unnecessary files.

I'm trying to get the following result:

```
Common/Components/Component
Common/Components/Component1
Common/Components/Component2
Common/Components/Component3
Common/Components/Component4
Common/Components/Component5
Common/Components/Component6
Comp
App
```

The file looks like this:

```
-I../../../Common/Component -I../../../Common/Component1 -I../../../Common/Component2 -I../../../Common/Component3 -I../../../Common/Component4 -I../../../Common/Component5 -I../../../Common/Component6 -IComp  -IApp  ../../../
```

I want to know how the best way to transform input format to output format standard text-processing tool with 1 call with `sed` tool or `awk`.

Comment: There is nothing in any of your sed scripts that would convert `/Common/Component5` to `Common/Components/Component5` so either that's a mistake in your posted scripts or a mistake in your sample input/output. Your first sed script also contains a syntax error and your last 2 commands have the `>` in the wrong place. Please [edit] your question to show the actual scripts and sample input/output you want help with.

Comment: By saying `My goal is to join multiple sed commands into one` you already got an answer that does exactly that, but doing that won't necessarily provide the best way to get the output you want from the input you provided so do you **really** just want to know how to join your sed commands into one call to sed or do you instead want to know how best to transform your input format to your output format with 1 call to a standard text-processing tool such as sed or awk?

Comment: @EdMorton I want to know how the best way to transform my input format to my output format with 1 call, I edited my question, thanks for the clarification notice

Comment: You're welcome, please also fix the syntax errors in your code and the error in your example where `Components` appears out of nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='-I\\S+' 'RT{sub(/^-I.*Common\//,"Common/Components/",RT);sub(/^-I/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

output with samples will be as follows:

```
Common/Components/Component
Common/Components/Component1
Common/Components/Component2
Common/Components/Component3
Common/Components/Component4
Common/Components/Component5
Common/Components/Component6
Comp
App
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, in GNU `awk`. Setting `RS`(record separator) as `-I\\S+` -I till a space comes. In main `awk` program, check if `RT` is NOT NULL, substitute starting `-I` till Common with `Common/Components/` in RT and then substitute starting `-I` with NULL in RT. Then printing RT here.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't REALLY want the string `/Components` to be added in the middle of some output lines then this may be what you want, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v RS=' ' 'sub("^-I[./]*","")' file
Common/Component
Common/Component1
Common/Component2
Common/Component3
Common/Component4
Common/Component5
Common/Component6
Comp
App
```

That would fail if any of the paths in your input contained blanks but you don't show that as a possibility in your question so I assume it can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
sed -i 's/\-I\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.//\n/g
s/\-I/\n/g
/^[[:space:]]*$/d
s/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.//g' example.txt
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in one command?

Comment: @DorShamay that IS one command (i.e. 1 call to sed).

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný you don't need to escape `-` in a regexp, it's already literal unless used in a bracket expression. I'd recommend using some char other than `/` as the sed delimiter when using `/` inside the script so you don't need to escape the `/`s, e.g. instead of `s/\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.//g'` you could use `s:\.\./\.\./\.\.::g'`.

Comment: sorry let me rephrase, @Přemysl Šťastný how sed reacts to your answer? as 4 expressions?

Comment: @DorShamay Yes, it works like 4 separate expressions.